# Error Receiving Broadcast Intent Problem

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I created a broadcast receiver in the main activity and the background service which is sending broadcast intents. The application crashes each time I try to run it and the Log displays the following error message:

> 10-04 13:30:43.218:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(695):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
>   receiving broadcast Intent {
>   action=com.client.gaitlink.CommunicationService.action.LOGIN_STATUS_UPDATE
>   (has extras) } in
>   com.client.gaitlink.GaitLink$LoginStatusReceiver@431690e8

The broadcast message is sent from CommunicationService class in the following method:

```
private void announceLoginStatus(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(LOGIN_STATUS_UPDATE);
    intent.putExtra(SERVER_MESSAGE, mServerResponseMessage);
    intent.putExtra(SESSION_STRING, mSessionString);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

where

```
String LOGIN_STATUS_UPDATE = "com.client.gaitlink.CommunicationService.action.LOGIN_STATUS_UPDATE"
```

in the main activity the following broadcast reveiver is defined:

```
public class LoginStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String serverMessage = intent.getStringExtra(CommunicationService.SERVER_MESSAGE);
            String sessionString = intent.getStringExtra(CommunicationService.SESSION_STRING);

            userInfo.setSessionString(sessionString);
            saveSettings();
        }
    }
```

and registered in onResume method:

```
        IntentFilter loginStatusFilter;
        loginStatusFilter = new IntentFilter(CommunicationService.LOGIN_STATUS_UPDATE);
        loginStatusReceiver = new LoginStatusReceiver();
        registerReceiver(loginStatusReceiver, loginStatusFilter);
```

And the manifest file includes the following:

```
<activity android:name=".GaitLink"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            ...
            <action android:name="com.client.gaitlink.CommunicationService.action.LOGIN_STATUS_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could explain why the Log displays the message above and the application crashes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you gone step by step in the debugger to find exactly where the crash occurs?

One thing to look out for is if you are overriding any Android lifecycle events that you are properly calling the base class's constructor when necessary.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what the problem was?

Answer (score 11):

I solved it by adding `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` when you start a new `activity`.

If not started from an `activity`, `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` is needed.

Answer (score 7):

You have two `Intent` filters; you only need one. If you register the `BroadcastReceiver` via `registerReceiver()`, only use the `IntentFilter` that is the second parameter to that API call -- do not also put an `<intent-filter>` element in the `<activity>` in the manifest.

I do not know for certain if that is your problem, but it certainly does not help.

Comment: Please note that you must anyway register receiver for all intents, not a single generic empty intent.

Answer (score 5):

when you are looking at error logs, you are just looking at first few lines.
but surprisingly actual problem is mentioned in lines way below it-

```
Fatal Error : Main
error receiving broadcast...bla bla bla  <- you are just looking here only
at x.y.z.....
at x.y.z......
at x.y.z.....
at x.y.z......
caused by : ........................... <- but actual problem is here!
at x.y.z.....
at x.y.z......
at x.y.z.....
at x.y.z......
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use life cycle method  `onPause()` and `onResume()` Method for unregister and register broadcast intent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can understand what I want to say, because of my English.

I think this line of code is cause of a problem:

```java
userInfo.setSessionString(sessionString);
```

My project was wrong because I want to:

```java
int i = Integer.parseint(intent.getExtars("9"));
```

and you register two times.

Answer (score 0):

I found that making sure the intent was run from the original activity and putting things into one class got rid of the entire issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I think many people would still be searching answers for it. My situation is quite similar to this one.

What I wanted to do, is to call finish() in the child activity when certain events occur in parent activity i.e. by sending the broadcast message from MainActivity to Child Activity.

Following is the code in MainActivity when the event is occurred (e.g. when network connection is broken etc etc):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("ACTIVITY_FINISH");
    intent.putExtra("FinishMsg","ACTIVITY_FINISH: Network broken.");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In the child activity's OnResume() function:

```
    IntentFilter quitFilter = new IntentFilter();
    quitFilter.addAction("ACTIVITY_FINISH");
    registerReceiver(m_quitReceiver, quitFilter);
```

In the child activity's OnPause() function:

```
    unregisterReceiver(m_quitReceiver);
```

Within the child activity class:

```
BroadcastReceiver m_quitReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) 
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("ACTIVITY_FINISH"))
        {
            Log.d("INFO", intent.getExtras().getString("FinishMsg"));
            finish(); // do here whatever you want
        }
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It might because you keep registering BroadcastReceiver. I made that mistake before as a result it returns this error. Make sure BroadcastReceiver only registered once.

Answer (score -5):

Ok what worked for me was declaring the `onNotification` method as follows:

```
    window.onNotification = function(event) {
    alert('onNotification called!');
};
```